# Add text below icons

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-mobile, uwp, uwp-xaml

Some apps have the ability to show or hide an icon's name right under the icon in Windows 10 Mobile. The text's visibility is toggled when the user clicks on the 3 dots beside the icons - Photos, OneDrive, Outlook,...

Is that done by some ui element property or some other built in way, or was it just written to behave the same from scratch? My goal, of course, is to add that to my app.

Comment: Show or hide an icon's name... *where*?

Comment: @CodyGray Right under it.

Comment: Well, that didn't really help. I'm still having a hard time picturing what interface you're talking about. Are you thinking of notification icons in the taskbar's notification area? Or something else entirely? Perhaps a screenshot would be helpful...?

Comment: any reason you can't include the text in your icons? that's my preference.

Comment: @CodyGray I updated the question. It's in Windows 10 Mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about the `Command Bar` control

You can read more on how to customize the AppBar in the official [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/app-bars?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Thanks!